# Django render не открывает html страницу

Tags: python, django, render

**view**

```
def file_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('я тут post')
        return render(request, 'files.html', {})
    else:
        print('я тут get')
        return render(request, 'files.html', {})
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.dropzone_uploads),
    path('fileupload/', views.file_upload),

]
```

**командная строка**

```
[09/Jun/2021 01:04:48] "GET /upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3307
я тут post
[09/Jun/2021 01:04:52] "POST /upload/fileupload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

**files.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="fileupload/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: templates]

т.е тело view выполняется, а return render нет.

Comment: Так может, шаблон files.html пустой или поломанный просто?

Comment: добавила содержимое files.html

Comment: Это точно единственный files.html в вашем проекте?

Comment: да, прикрепила скрин

Comment: ошибок нет? попробуйте на другом шаблоне

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы не указали приложение в INSTALLED_APPS в файле settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'core'
]
```

Либо можете указать папку для шаблона в TEMPLATES:

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
       ...
       'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
        ],
   }
]
```

Так же можно подробно изучить [основы Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: Скорее всего нет, тк автор указала `т.е тело view выполняется, а return render нет.`